# How to get the ID of the column on gridview radiobutton click

Tags: asp.net

I have one radio button in gridview itemplate field. But when I am selecting the radiobutton i am unable to get the id of that row. So that based on that id textbox value will be autopopulated.

```
enter code here

     <asp:GridView ID="gvItem" SkinID="GridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvItem_RowDataBound">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="false">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%#Container.DataItemIndex %>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnQuantity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbtnQuantity_CheckedChanged" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="20px" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <%--1--%>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ItemStyle Width="90px" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <%--2--%>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ItemStyle Width="140px" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>


                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try on the radiobutton click event to look for sender.parent.findcontrol("lblID").
this would be on the code-behind and for vb.net it would look like this:

```
Dim rowID as String = CType(CType(sender, RadioButton).Parent.FindControl("lblID"),Label).Text
```